# data selection Lost when double click on datatable row and display dialog Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable, when i double click on a row I display a dialog which contains tabview, 
the problem is when i want to change tabs I cannot get the selection object (of the row)

I use ajax for double clicking and for change tabs:

```
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect"  listener="#{beanView.onGridSelect}" update=":frm:dialog1" 
                   process="@this" />

<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{beanView.onUpdate}" update=":frm:tabs"  process="@this"/>
```

and for datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="dt_global" var="grid" value="#{beanView.list}"  tableStyle="width:auto"   rowKey="#{grid.id}" selection="#{beanView.list_selected}"
                                  widgetVar="rtTable"  paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                  style="font-size:11px;"  scrollable="true"  resizableColumns="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                  rowsPerPageTemplate="#{beanView.rowsPerPageTemplate}" rows="10" >
```

Please can you help me